# SharePoint template option missing

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, templates, publishing

I believe I have read this somewhere, but I can't find it nomatter how I search. I need to create a site collection using the **"Publishing Site with Workflow"** template. Unfortunately, that template is not available as an option. The SharePoint installation is an Enterprise license and all enterprise features are enabled. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are searching the **"Publishing Site with Workflow"** for creating a Site Collection.But there are two types of templates one that is marked with **SubWebOnly=TRUE** and others that are marked as **RootSiteOnly="True"** as the name say it will be visible at that particular level. Being said that **"Publishing Site with Workflow"** is marked with **SubWebOnly=TRUE** so it will be visible when you create a Sub Web not the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

You probably only require a normal publishing portal site collection.